# Structural induction proof for reverse(push(as, bs)) = push(reverse(bs), reverse(as))

Tags: programming-languages, induction, tail-recursion

I need to prove:

```
reverse(push(as,bs)) = push(reverse(bs), reverse(as))
```

where:

```
def push[T](as: List[T], bs: List[T]): 
  List [T] = as match {
      case Nil => bs
      case x::xs => x::push(xs, bs)
  }

def reverse[T](ls: List[T]): 
  List[T] = ls match {
     case Nil => Nil
     case x::xs => push(reverse(xs), x::Nil)
  }
```

I am already stuck in the base case, since i cant figure out a lemma.
The only thing I have this far is:

```
reverse(push(Nil,bs)) = reverse(bs)
```

and I'm stuck here since it felt eternity.

Does anyone have an idea for a lemma?

Comment: Have you tried proving `push(xs, Nil) = xs`? Have you tried proving the equality when `as` is a list of single item?

Answer (score 1):

I think what would help a lot is proving first that `push(push(a, b), c) = push(a, push(b, c))`.

Once you have that result, you can make an induction on `as` only in the equality `reverse(push(as,bs)) = push(reverse(bs), reverse(as))`.

I will add some details if necessary.